# Is there a bitwise equivalent of boolA == boolB?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I know I can do `bool ^= true` to reverse its value but is there a similar operator to evaluate `boolA == boolB` without the == operator? I don't know  much about bitwise but I haven't found any answer online yet.

It would be something like

```
bool a = false;
bool b = true;
bool c = a /*some sign, like ^ or ~ or something */ b;
Debug.Log(c);
// output: false
```

Comment: I'm sure you could concoct something, but you'd use `==` when comparing bitfields as well as when comparing bools

Comment: @canton7 I think he means to compare the numbers bitwise and put a 1 if the two current bits are equal

Comment: @CoderCharmander I don't want to manipulate the bits, only the booleans in C#

Comment: @ThéoDriutti You mean to test boolean equality without the `==` operator?

Comment: The @CoderCharmander answer is fine and standard. But you must know that it is not CPU optimized because a single test [CMP](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow#Unconditional_Jumps) and  [JE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow#Jump_if_Equal) is the fastest in terms of CPU clocks. Using bitwise operators, after, you also need in addition to use JMP and JE... Such a replacement is only usefull in multiple calculations and complex equations (like for 3D), and there, you will get optimizations.

Comment: @CoderCharmander yes I don't know if it's doable maybe it's stupid

Comment: If it's efficiency you're concerned about, don't worry: `int result = (a==b)?1:0;` is handled well by the optimisation (both via IL and the JITTer).

Comment: @ThéoDriutti Maybe you want to use `.Equals`? `a.Equals(b)` is really similar to `a == b`

Comment: @CoderCharmander the point of my question was to find a bitwise operator

Comment: @ThéoDriutti You mean a binary operator? Please edit your question to show an example of how would you use it.

Comment: @ThéoDriutti Well, you could check for non-equality, then invert the result: `!(a != b)`. But you can just use `==`.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use the XOR operator (`^`). XOR returns 1 if the input bits are different, so it can be counted as a bitwise `!=`. After that, you can invert the bits with the `~` (NOT) unary operator. You can do it like this:

```
~(0b1010 ^ 0b1100) // 0b1001
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just be the same as doing a bitwise AND (&)? `0x0b101 & 0x0b110 == 0x0b100`

Comment: @Icemanind A bitwise AND returns 0 for `0 & 0`, not 1 as it should test the bitwise equality.

Comment: Ahh I see. You're not just comparing which bits are both turned on. You're seeing which bits are equal. Gotcha! Thanks for the clarification.